# Why is my variable saying it is undefined?

Tags: javascript, css, this

I'm not sure why my 'name' variable is undefined when you click the 'Add List' button.

Here's the suspected problem code:

```
function addList() {
            let name = prompt("What would you like your list to be called?");
            console.log(name);
            if (name != null) {
                console.log(name);
                let name = new list(`${name}`, "[]");
                const markup = `
                    <div id="${name}">
                    ${this.name} List:
                    <br>
                    ${this.items}
                    <br>
                    ${this.button}
                    <br>
                    </div>
                    `;
                document.getElementById("Shopping").append(markup);

            }
            return;
        }
```

Here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/vaughnick/pen/YYBoeq

Thanks for any insight/ tutorials you can link for me in my journey :)

Comment: Which variable? Tell us where you're seeing the problem; nothing immediately obvious happens in the codepen.

Comment: The pen does not reproduce the issue you're describing. It's recommended you add a [mcve] in the question itself, so your question remains relevant for future users.

Comment: Sorry, the name variable is undefined.

Comment: Ill be deleting this, or I will make it useful for others as soon as I know whats going on. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have two variables called `name`. As `let` is block-scoped variable, `name` which you are referring to is declared in the next line. This causes your error. You can either change second variable name or remove `let` to avoid creating new variable with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

let is scoped and by redefining it in the if {} block, it creates a new temporary variable.  Before it creates it, it is therefore undefined.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let